# Calculate surface of objects (rocks) in an image with lots of noise

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Is there a way to caculate the size/surface of every individual rock visible in this image?

I have tried:

1. Contours - this doesnt seem to work the contours touch, gets real messy.
2. Watershed algorithm -  I couldn't get the algorithm to work in my situation.
3. Sharpening -> binary image -> contours   -   wasnt pretty

If anyone can direct me in the right way I'd be very thankful.
Cheers!

[image: The image]

Comment: to which end are you doing it? Is it to make a histogram of grit sizes? I feel like there might actually be a trade-off there in that case, where you trade the ability to recognize every single contour for a smooth grading.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hey thanks for your comment, what I want to do is calculate the average stone size/surface every 10 cm or so. So about 3 times in this example.

Comment: have you tried whether the amount of sharp edges in a region would be a good proxy for that?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have no idea what that means so I'll be on Google..

Comment: I meant "count the area of sharp edges in a part of an image. If that amount is high, there's many small rocks in there. That is probably somewhat monotonic function of the rock size distribution". So, if you can more easily count "edge pixels", and then "calibrate" your method to say "I've tried and manually counted rock sizes in a dozen of pictures, and that's how the percentage of edge pixels corresponds to a rock size distribution", you can do the easy thing instead of the hard thing

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ah I get it.. I think..  Tho this approach works with averages, and I need a specific number, lets say: I need to be able to find the biggest single rock in the image and calculate the surface of that rock :/

Comment: ah, OK! Yeah, that seems harder, indeed :)

Comment: Thank you for your time tho ^^